# How to find the index of a value in an array and use it to display a value in another array with the same index

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I am new to Python and I have been stuck trying out a "simple banking program".

I have got everything right except for this bit:

> If the user types S then:
> Ask the user for the account number.
> Search the array for that account number and find its position in the accountnumbers array.
> Display the Name, and balance at the position found during the above search.

Originally it was just supposed to be through accounts 1-5, but now I am having trouble coming up with a way to search the account numbers if they are any number, not just 1 - 5. For example

> The user makes his account numbers 34, 445, 340,2354 and 3245. Completely random account numbers with no order.

Here is what I have so far

```
names = []
accountNumbers = []
balance = []

def displaymenu():
    print("**** MENU OPTIONS ****")
    print("Type P to populate accounts")
    print("Type S to search for account")
    print("Type E to exit")
    choiceInput()

def choiceInput():   
    choice = str(input("Please enter your choice: "))
    if (choice == "P"):
        populateAccount()
    
    elif (choice == "S"):
        accountNumb = int(input("Please enter the account number to search: "))
        if (accountNumb > 0) and (accountNumb < 6):
            print("Name is: " + str(names[accountNumb - 1]))
            print(names[accountNumb - 1] + " account has the balance of : $" + str(balance[accountNumb -1]))
        elif (accountNumb == accountNumbers):
            index = names.index(accountNumb)
            accountNumb = index
            print(names[accountNumb - 1] + " account has the balance of : $" + str(balance[accountNumb -1]))
        else:
            print("The account number not found!")
    
    elif (choice == "E"):
        print("Thank you for using the program.")
        print("Bye")
        raise SystemExit
    
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again!")
    displaymenu()

def populateAccount ():
        name = 0
        for name in range(5):
                Names = str(input("Please enter a name: "))
                names.append(Names)
                account ()
                name = name + 1
        
        
def account ():
    accountNumber = int(input("Please enter an account number: "))
    accountNumbers.append(accountNumbers)
    balances()
    
def balances ():
    balances = int(input("Please enter a balance: "))
    balance.append(balances)


displaymenu()
```

I have tried to use indexes and have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line of code
`if (accountNumb > 0) and (accountNumb < 6):`
with
`if (accountNumb > 0) and  (accountNumb < len(accountNumbers)):`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I messed up when appending the account number:

```
def account ():
    accountNumber = int(input("Please enter an account number: "))
    accountNumbers.append(accountNumbers)
    balances()
```

I appended

> accountNumbers

not

> accountNumber

the code should be

```
def account ():
    accountNumber = int(input("Please enter an account number: "))
    accountNumbers.append(accountNumber)
    balances()
```

also the searchArray function I made was:

```
def searchArray(accountNumbers):
    x = int(input("Please enter an account number to search: "))
    y = accountNumbers.index(x)
    print("Name is: " + str(names[y]))
    print(str(names[y]) + " account has a balance of: " + str(balance[y]))
```

rookie mistake , shouldnt be using such similar object names.